# How to filter "and not in" in Django query with Q?

Tags: python, sql, django

I am working on Django project and basically it is kinda custom article system. So we have articles that are divided in Circle and Region. So for example I have Region1, Region2 and Region3 regions. Similarly I have Circle1, Circle2 and Circle3 circles. I have user that belong to one region and one circle. So lets say my user, User1 belongs to Region1 and Circle2.

I have Article1 that was posted for Region1 and Circle1, Article2 that was posted for Region1 and Circle2, Article3 was posted for Region2 and Circle2.

I need to filter article for this user in following way.

`Get me article(s) that belongs to my circle and not to my region, get me article(s) that belongs my circle and region both.`

What I have done so far is,

```
Article.object.filter(is_archived=False).filter(
                    Q(belongs_to_circle=self.cid) & Q(belongs_to_region=self.rid) |
                    Q(belongs_to_circle=self.cid) & ~Q(belongs_to_region=self.rid)
                )
```

If I use to query to get articles that belongs to circle and region both, it works fine but I am trying to get articles that belongs to my circle but not in my region.

So if Article was posted for Region1 and Circle2 I should get it. If Article was posted for Region2 and Circle2 I should get it, but if an Article was posted for Region1 and Circle1 I should not get it. Can anyone help me to get this query properly?

`self.cid` and `self.rid` are also model object as I have Region and Circle models and the are foreign key for Article.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.exclude()` for that.

```
Article.object.filter(is_archived=False,belongs_to_circle=self.cid).exclude(belongs_to_region=self.rid)
```

Comment: `Article.object.filter(is_archived=False, belongs_to_circle=self.cid).exclude(belongs_to_region=self.rid)` would be better, i think so

Comment: Thanks for the help @Astik, but I was thinking it at wrong way. Just changed the filter process. We will just query where it belongs to both!

Comment: @AstikAnand, your answer is kind of right but not in the scenario I mentioned. But I will give it up-vote for sure.